# ActionbarSherlock - how do I implement a tab navigation once and have that used in my app?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am looking at the tab navigation example from the ActionbarSherlock download. The examples show one element type per class. But I would like all my screens to reuse the tab navigation.

So I added the tab_navigation.xml to my project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dip">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/tab_navigation_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And now I am wondering how I can add the code for the tabs to my project? Do I absolutely have to define the tabs in every Activity? Or is there a way to just have one definition I can reuse in multiple places?

Here is how my activities look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Fragments

Whether you have seen this?

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-navigation-tabs-containing-listview-to-action-bar-in-pre-honeycomb-versions-using-sherlock-library/

Answer (score 2):

the tabs are defined on a per activity basis. This means if you wish to use tabs on each activity you must add the tabs (via xml or via code on each activity).

The proper way to handle such a situation is to use fragments. I would suggest you use various fragments and just add or remove them as needed while keeping the same activity and the same tab navigation. This is also the preferred method according to the Android best practices.t

If you really insist on not using fragment (not recommended) then you could create a base activity class that creates the tab navigation and then inherit from it (rather than inheriting directly from SherlockFragmentActivity), however that would be somewhat hacky in my mind, and I'd recommend you stick with fragments the way the Android guys designed it :)